# How to see OpenMp environment variable of running process

Tags: linux, openmp

I have a process which is supposed to use OpenMP, and I would like to verify whether an environment variable is set to the expected value.

I tried to read the environment variables of my program's process but can't find any OpenMP variable.

My question is: Can I see the OpenMP environment variable within my process with a terminal?

Is there a way to get an OpenMp status using a terminal?

Comment: You can look at `/proc/<pid>/environ` to find out the environment variables of a running process.  Not sure if that's what you want here.

Comment: That is where i was looking at, but the environment variables (for openMp)  are not there.

Comment: Are you sure that any of those variables are set?  If unset, OpenMP will act in a sane default manner.

Comment: @codeforester, it's worth mentioning `tr '\0' '\n'` when looking at `/proc/.../environ`, to get something a bit more readable.

Comment: Looking at the code, yes they should be set. I want to see the OpenMP environment variables to validate it. I`m new on the project which is BIG and ressources & internal documentations are... close to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are seeing other environment variable but not the OpenMP ones, it could be because the environment variable [OMP_DISPLAY_ENV](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSXVZZ_13.1.5/com.ibm.xlcpp1315.lelinux.doc/compiler_ref/omp_display_env.html) is not set. If it`s not, then nothing will be shown.